# Sketchup crashes with.rbs scrambled plugin

Tags: ruby, plugins, sketchup, scramble

I have a plugin for Sketchup that is used by clients, and because this I need to Scrambler it to create a .rbs file.
When the file is .rb, works perfectly, but when I scramble it to .rbs, the plugin crashes the Sketchup on Startup.
Anyone know these problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem once, my plugin.rb checked if webdialog was already created before you created there again.

```
if mywebdialog.nil?;
     mywebdialog = UI :: WebDialog.new ("" ......
```

This code works in sketchup when it is .rb when it encrypts with Scramble .rbs it gives an error that is triggered BugSplat ... al checks in your code is not doing it.

Remove the "if mywebdialog.nil?;" And test again!

Comment: Under what OS and SketchUp version does this happen? With this exact snippet?

Comment: thomthom, OSX 10.8.2 and Win7, this code result in Bug Splat message.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the webDialog is created before create another one.